# node - Parse iptc data from image buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, iptc

Trying to find a way to extract IPTC data from an image file buffer, there are existing libraries available on npm that allow you to open and read a file from the local filesystem but i am storing files on AWS S3 and would prefer to use buffers instead of creating unnecessary disk writes.

Not sure where to start, maybe start looking through how this module works:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-iptc
And create my own module? Or is there an easier way that i've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to extract IPTC data by using

```
var iptc = require('node-iptc');
var iptc_data = iptc(imageData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also there's an isomorphic library [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr) that works in both Node.js and browser. And it works with the new HEIC image format as well.

```js
exifr.parse(input, {iptc: true}).then(output => {
  console.log('IPTC', output)
})
```

It parses multiple formats (TIFF/EXIF, ICC, IPTC, XMP, JFIF) but IPTC isn't enabled by default so you need to enabled it in options as seen in the example.